# Genexus: cuando ejecuto un store procedure no termina y me muestra la pantalla de acceso

Tags: genexus, timeout

estoy trabajando en Genexus 16, desde una pantalla ejecuto un store proceduere que llena una tabla temporal y luego en esa misma pantalla veo en un grid la información de la tabla temporal, pero cuando se procesa mucha información aproximadamente a los 25 minuntos me aparece la pantalla de acceso al sistema, no se si es un timeout o algo similar

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás generando en .NET, puedes manejar el timeout de la sesión en el archivo web.config del sitio, dentro del mismo en el tag <system.web>:

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="28800" maxRequestLength="20480" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="480" />
  </system.web>
```

En la línea 2, en **executionTimeout** el tiempo va en segundos (Especifica el tiempo máximo durante el cual una solicitud puede ejecutarse antes de que ASP.NET la cierre automáticamente)

En la línea 3, en **timeout** el tiempo va en minutos (Especifica el número de minutos que una sesión puede estar inactiva)

Comment: Si funcionó al agregar el timeout, muchas gracias¡¡